# Getstream - How do I display timeline feed based on its comment reactions?

Tags: getstream-io

I have a timeline feed for my website. The feeds are currently displaying in the order where latest feeds are displayed first. I would like to change the order of feed listing. Is it possible to list the activities in the feed based on the latest commented activity? That is latest comment reacted activity should be displayed first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely support this but you need to decide a field to rank on and update that field according to comments. A ranking function implements this idea:

```
{"score": "last_commented == 0 ? time : last_commented","defaults": {"last_commented": 0}}
```

It assumes you maintain comment timestamp in custom `last_commented` field on the activities.